# Is there any good reason to use Gnome Software Center over the distro's package manager?

Tags: package-management, opensuse

My question is simple: Is there any good reason to use Gnome Software Center over the distro's package manager?

I just decided to switch to Open SUSE Tumbleweed after six months using Arch, and by default the distro comes with Gnome Software installed. Is there any point of using it, over the default distro package manager? (a.k.a: zypper). To me, having more than one place to install software, just makes harder to update all softwares at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of Gnome Software Center is to use whatever package manager your distribution ships with. It does that via [package-kit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/PackageKit/) multiple [backends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackageKit#Front-ends) (and there are [other frontends](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PackageKit#Front-ends) besides Gnome Software Center).

So, you can decide which one to use based on the interface, available functions, ease of use ...

The result of installing a package with `zypper` or `gnome-software-center` should be the same.